# Выдает ошибку при подключении Angular Material , не работает команда 'ng'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Пробовал установку angular cli глобально , не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите ошибку и все поймете

Comment: Уже разобрался :))